# Is this a bad idea for remote connection?

Tags: bash, macos, netcat

If I have a Mac or other UNIX-Based system, and I wanted to grant remote access to a machine without them using a password and I didn't want to install anything, is it a bad practice to run `while true; do nc -l 4444 > sh.sh; sh sh.sh; done` on my computer and run `nc 192.168.x.x 4444` on my other computer to connect to the first one?

Comment: You might wanna look into **public key authentication**.

Comment: If privacy and someone hijacking the session to do something malicious like delete all the files are not a concern, then no it is not a bad idea. But I wouldn't use this for anything that requires reliability, or security.

Comment: Not a bad idea, if (and only if) your script runs as an unprivileged user and you give that user no harmful privileges; perhaps a chroot, if applicable, can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed it is a bad idea. Anybody has access to this machine, because you have no authentication or authorization mechanism.
On MacOS and any other Unix system there should be an ssh service running. You can create a ssh-key pair for every user that should be able to login and put the public key part in /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys (MacOS) or /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys (Linux). If there is no password set for the private key of the key pair, the user can login without password to the machine. But only users who have their keys stored on the machine. 
So you have control over the users that have access without needing a password for them.